# Suggestion on dynamo DB Table creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am creating New Table in Dynamo DB, following are Attributes:-

1. ProjectID
2. CreatedTime
3. JobID
4. JobType
5. Description
6. Message
7. Status

I have t search(query) items on "ProjectID", "CreatedTime" and "JobType" mostly.
Also I want to search(query) items on "JobID".
On "Status" also, but not always.

According to me

1. "ProjectID" will be primary partition key.
2. "CreatedTime" will be primary sort key.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In DynamoDB, using *primary partition key* and *sort key* creates a *composite key*. In other words, DynamoDB will allow creating multiple projects with same `ProjectID` but different `CreatedTime`, which is clearly undesirable.

You need to create a different a table with `ProjectID` *primary key* and create an index for each attribute you want to query by. In your case, you will need indexes for each of `JobType`, `JobID` and `Status`.

Also note that in order to find all *items* between two dates you must *scan* the table. *Scan* operation is very expensive you generally want to avoid because it uses *RCU* for every single item in table.